Setting up index.php deletion in url after installation in codeignator subdirectory/public_html?
CodeIgnitor was installed in rootFolder/sub, and the location of the index.php file was placed under the sub/public_html folder.
mydomain/
sub/
application/
system/
public_html/
index.php
.htaccess
The Apache setting is

Alias  /sub "D:\\programs\\code\\mydomain\\sub\\public_html"

DocumentRoot "D:\\programs\\code\\mydomain"
\<Directory "D:\\progras\\code\\mydomain"\>
...
\</Directory\>

.htaccess

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(index.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.\*)$ index.php/$1 \[L\]

local/sub/
local/sub/index.php/welcome
The welcome page was displayed normally when connected.
local/sub/welcome
The mod_rewrite error was output when connecting.
Looking at the mod_rewrite log
... \[perdir D:/programs/company_code/mydomain/sub/public_html/\] strip per-dir prefix: D:/programs/company_code/mydomain/sub/public_html/welcome -\> welcome
... \[perdir ...\] applying pattern '^(.\*)$' to uri 'welcome'
... \[perdir ...\] RewriteCond: input='/sub/welcome' pattern='!(index\\.php)' =\> matched
... \[perdir ...\] RewriteCond: input='D:/programs/company_code/mydomain/sub/public_html/welcome' pattern='!-f' =\> matched
... \[perdir ...\] RewriteCond: input='D:/programs/company_code/mydomain/sub/public_html/welcome' pattern='!-d' =\> matched
... \[perdir ...\] rewrite 'welcome' -\> 'index.php/welcome'
... \[perdir ...\] add per-dir prefix: index.php/welcome -\> D:/programs/company_code/mydomain/sub/public_html/index.php/welcome
... \[perdir ...\] strip document_root prefix: D:/programs/company_code/mydomain/sub/public_html/index.php/welcome -\> /sub/public_html/index.php/welcome
... \[perdir ...\] internal redirect with /sub/public_html/index.php/welcome \[INTERNAL REDIRECT\]
\[authz_core:debug\]  authorization result of Require all granted: granted
\[authz_core:debug\]  authorization result of \<RequireAny\>: granted

//I understand up to this log.
//I don't understand if it's public_html/public_html at the end of the pass below.

... \[perdir ...\] add path info postfix: D:/programs/company_code/mydomain/sub/public_html/public_html -\> D:/programs/company_code/mydomain/sub/public_html/public_html/index.php/welcome
... \[perdir ...\] strip per-dir prefix: D:/programs/company_code/mydomain/sub/public_html/public_html/index.php/welcome -\> public_html/index.php/welcome
... \[perdir ...\] applying pattern '^(.\*)$' to uri 'public_html/index.php/welcome'
... \[perdir ...\] RewriteCond: input='/sub/public_html/index.php/welcome' pattern='!(index\\.php)' =\> not-matched
... \[perdir ...\] pass through D:/programs/company_code/mydomain/sub/public_html/public_html
\[core:info\] \[client ::1:51910\] AH00128: File does not exist: D:/programs/company_code/mydomain/sub/public_html/public_html/index.php/welcome
\

How to change .htaccess
Can I access local/sub/welcome without index.php output?
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index\.php)

Find index.php in the first string in the string
I couldn't find the index.php between the strings, so I changed it as follows.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(index.php)

